# HTML PUT sails-filemaker

Tags: sails.js, filemaker

I've just started using sails-filemaker to talk to a filemaker server. I like it :-)
I'm looking for a way to handle a HTML PUT request to update a record.

The model is

```
    /**
    * LocalityFilemaker.js
    *
    * @description :: Suburbs (locality) in the evolution database.
    * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
    */

    module.exports = {

        connection: 'filemaker', 
        tableName: 'locality-sails-layout',

      attributes: {
            id: {
                type: 'integer',
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            }, 
            suburb: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            state: {
                type: 'string'
            },
            postcode: {
                type: 'string'
            }

      }

    };
```

When I call a get to {{url}}/localityFilemaker/12600 I get the response.

```
    {
      "id": 12600,
      "suburb": "LARGS BAY",
      "state": "SA",
      "postcode": "5016",
      "modid": "3",
      "recid": "29500",
      "createdAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

When I call a put to {{url}}/localityFilemaker/12600 or {{url}}/localityFilemaker

```
    {
      "id": 12600,
      "suburb": "LARGS BAY.",
      "state": "SA",
      "postcode": "5016",
      "recid": "29500"
    }
```

I get 400 Bad request. What is the best way to update a record using sails-filemaker using a PUT HTML request?

Comment: I suspect you need to exclude recid from your update json, but the best thing to do would be to ask the developer - Todd Geist of Geist Interactive.

Comment: Thanks @nicolai.kant - that worked. Would you like to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope Todd will correct me if I am wrong. It looks like "recid" is a FileMaker internal Record id and your put is trying to update it. Remove "recid" from your put JSON and it should work.

Comment: yes nicolai.kant is right. Its an internal ID.  sails-filemaker doesn't use it to find the record to update, as this wouldn't be standard Sails/Waterline behavior or very RESTFUL It uses the primary key as defined by the model.

It should be noted that this does require two requests to the DB to be made. The first to find the recid and the next to use the recid to update the record.

Comment: One more thing to note.  the modid CAN be passed back. If you do pass it back it must match the modid of the server record, or the request will fail.  This gives you a way to avoid overwriting changes that have happened on the server. Its a simple form of concurrency control.  Most times you can just leave modid out, but if you need the extra concurency control you have it

Comment: Thanks for clarification, Todd and btw thanks for the module.